# Object does not get loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the weirdest thing ever happened to me with ruby/rails.

I have a model, *Store*, which has_many *Balances*. And I have a method that gives me the default balance based on the store's currency.

**Store model.**

```rb
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :balances, as: :balanceable, dependent: :destroy

  def default_balance
    #puts self.inspect <- weird part.
    balances.where(currency: self.currency)[0]
  end
  ...
end
```

**Balance model.**

```rb
class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :balanceable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

Ok, so then in the Balance controller I have the *show* action, that will give me a specific balance or the default one.

**Balance controller.**

```rb
class Api::Stores::BalancesController < Api::Stores::BaseController

  before_filter :load_store

  # Returns a specific alert
  # +URL+:: GET /api/stores/:store_id/balances/:id
  def show
    #puts @store.inspect <- weird part.
    @balance = (params[:id] == "default") ? @store.default_balance : Balance.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @balance, :api_template => :default
  end
  ...

  private
    # Provides a shortcut to access the current store
    def load_store
      @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
      authorize! :manage, @store
    end
end
```

Now here is where the weird part comes...

If I make a call to the show action; for example:

> GET /api/stores/148/balances/default

It returns null (because the currency was set as null, and there is no Balance with null currency), and the SQL query generated is:

```sql
SELECT `balances`.* FROM `balances` WHERE `balances`.`balanceable_id` = 148 AND `balances`.`balanceable_type` = 'Store' AND `balances`.`currency` IS NULL
```

So I DON'T know why... it is setting the *currency* as NULL. **BUT** if in any where in that process I put

> puts @store.inspect

or inside the `default_balance` method:

> puts self.inspect

it magically works!!!.

So I don't know why is that happening?... It seems like the store object is not getting loaded until I "*inspect*" it or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: Is `currency` a column of table stores?

Comment: Yes, it is.
`currency :string(255)`

Comment: try debugging the objects before the query

Comment: Could you check if the query loading `@store` properly load all columns (ie: contain `SELECT stores.*`) ?

Comment: Please check that @store.currency or self.currency is present or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally after a lot of debugging, I found the reason...

In the *Store* model I have a method_missing method and I had it like this:

```rb
def method_missing method_name, *args
  if method_name =~ /^(\w+)_togo$/
    send($1, *args).where(togo: true)
  elsif method_name =~ /^(\w+)_tostay$/
    send($1, *args).where(tostay: true)
  end
end
```

So when I was calling `self.currency` it went first to the method_missing and then returned *null*. What I was missing here was the `super` call.

```rb
def method_missing method_name, *args
  if method_name =~ /^(\w+)_togo$/
    send($1, *args).where(togo: true)
  elsif method_name =~ /^(\w+)_tostay$/
    send($1, *args).where(tostay: true)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

But I continue wondering why after I had called `puts @store.inspect` or `puts self.inspect` it worked well?. I mean, why in that case that `super` call wasn't needed?

Comment: Probably because `inspect` make a call which define methods for all column in the table.

Comment: Adrien is right–`inspect` is defined in `Object` from which yours implicitly descends. `method_missing` only gets called if the method isn't found in the class nor any of its ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

Sam and Adrien are on the right path.

ActiveRecord overrides method_missing to add a whole bunch of dynamic methods including the accessors for the column-backed attributes like Store#currency.  While I'm glossing over a lot, suffice it to say that when the logic is invoked then the dynamic class/instance methods are added to the Store class/instances so that subsequent calls no longer require the method_missing hook.

When YOU overrode method_missing without calling super, you effectively disabled this functionality.  Fortunately, this functionality can be invoked by other means, one of which you tripped upon when you called store#inspect.

By adding the call to super, you simply assured that ActiveRecord's dynamic methods are always added to the class when they're needed.